# Beginner C# User Input/Convert/Switch Statement Question

Tags: c#, switch-statement, user-input, calculator

I am a beginner, and I just started to write a simple calculator program in C#, and when I run my app in terminal, it's user input will still have ReadLine after I press enter, if I press enter twice, these codes is given out

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
```

Here is my codes

```cs
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor First Number");
      Console.ReadLine();
      int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Second Number");
      Console.ReadLine();
      int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Choose your calculation");
      Console.WriteLine("Type + for Addition");
      Console.WriteLine("Type - for Subtraction");
      Console.WriteLine("Type * for Multiplication");
      Console.WriteLine("Type / for Division");
      Console.ReadLine();
      string expression = Console.ReadLine();
      switch(expression) 
      {
        case "+":
          Console.WriteLine(x+y);
        break;
        case "-":
          Console.WriteLine(x-y);
        break;
        case "*":
          Console.WriteLine(x*y);
        break;
        case "/":
          Console.WriteLine(x/y);
        break;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the user input, is it a valid int or empty
if it is not a valid number you have to make it enter the number again

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  public class Program
  {
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
         FirstNumber:
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor First Number");
      string stringX = Console.ReadLine();
      int x = 0;
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringX) || !int.TryParse(stringX, out x)){
            goto FirstNumber;
        }
        
         SecondNumber:
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Second Number");
      string stringY = Console.ReadLine();
      int y = 0;
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringY) || !int.TryParse(stringY, out y)){
            goto SecondNumber;
        }
        
         Expression:
      Console.WriteLine("Choose your calculation");
      Console.WriteLine("Type + for Addition");
      Console.WriteLine("Type - for Subtraction");
      Console.WriteLine("Type * for Multiplication");
      Console.WriteLine("Type / for Division");

      string expression = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if(expression!="+" && expression!="-" && expression!="/" && expression!="*"){
            goto Expression;
        }
      switch(expression) 
      {
        case "+":
          Console.WriteLine(x+y);
        break;
        case "-":
          Console.WriteLine(x-y);
        break;
        case "*":
          Console.WriteLine(x*y);
        break;
        case "/":
          Console.WriteLine(x/y);
        break;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you enter twice, next `ReadLine` method gets called and it’s not a valid integer value. So you should always check whether the value is convertible to integer or not. You can use `int.TryParse` method. You can also debug by using try catch block.

Comment: @KennethCho enjoy your time